# Ошибка Error:unsupported class file version 52.0.Что делать?

Tags: java, android

```
Error:unsupported class file version 52.0
Error:PARSE ERROR:
Error:1 error; aborting
Error:...while parsing com/mysql/jdbc/JDBC42CallableStatement.class
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
```

Что за ошибка и как ее исправить. Как правильно поставить jdbc?

Comment: Какая версия `buildTools` используется? Я постоянно получаю эту ошибку в 24.0.0 версии. Из за этого использую версию 23.0.3

Comment: Ага, а ещё можно попробовать сменить яву на 7 версию (т.е. 1.7)

Answer (score 1):

Здесь [упоминалось об этой несовместимости](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8-compatibility-guide.html):

> The class file version for Java SE 8 is 52.0 as per the JVM Specification. Version 52.0 class files produced by a Java SE 8 compiler cannot be used in earlier releases of Java SE.

Поставте JDK 1.7 и скомпилируйте заново.